# How can I get props in this case?

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning HOC, I have a question how is it possible to get `props` in HOC in this case.

withRainbow.js(HOC)

```
import React from 'react';

const withRainbow = (WrappedComponent) => {
    const colors = ['red', 'blue', 'orange'];
    const randomColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * 3)];
    const className = randomColor + '-text';

    return ( props ) => {
        return (
            <div className={className}>
                <WrappedComponent {...props}/>
            </div>
        )
    };
}

export default withRainbow;
```

About.jsx

```
import React from 'react';
import withRainbow from '../hoc/withRainbox';

const About = () => {
    return ( 
        <div className="container">
            <h4 className="center">About</h4>
            <p>This is about yay!</p>
        </div>
     );
}

export default withRainbow(About);
```

1. How is it possible to get `props` through callback `return (props) => ...` in `withRainbow.js` even though `withRainbow(About)` in `About.jsx` has no argument `props`?
2. If `About.jsx` has `state`, can I get it too in `withRainbow.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is it possible to get props through callback return (props) => ...
>   in withRainbow.js even though withRainbow(About) in About.jsx has no
>   argument props?

`withRainbow(About)` returns a new component to which if you pass props while rendering, it can access props like you do in the withRainbow HOC event though you aren't access props in the `About` component.

```
const AboutWithRainbow = withRainbow(About);
...
return (
   <AboutWithRainbow abc={'2433'} />
)
```

> If About.jsx has state, can I get it too in withRainbow.js?

No you shouldn't access state of a child component in parent. If these is such a case, you must lift the state up

Answer (score 1):

There is a confusion because you are looking at it in the wrong direction.

The props that the function receives are not from child component that you are exporting as `withRainbow(About)`.

It is coming from the parent component that is calling `withRainbow(About)`

```
// In about component.
const AboutWithRainbow = withRainbow(About);

// In parent component
<AboutWithRainbow {...propsFromParent} />
```

These are the props being received in the HOC component.

This also answers the second question. No, you cannot get state as an argument because [data flows down](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html).